# How do I break up EventAccessIds = 1+4+8 to EventId= 1, EventId = 4, and EventId = 8 in Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

User has access to specific Events. I have a row in Users called EventAccessIds. I want to have all of the ids the user can access here in some way. If user A should access events 1,4, and 8, then EventAccessIds should be 1+4+8 or something like that.

Then I want to pull out those Ids and use a Select statement to fill the data in different areas (dropdownlists, gridviews, etc). Essentially it will fill the data for the event ids of 1, 4, and 8 for the user A.

The problem is, I am new to databases and sql, so I am not so sure how to code all of this. I am using Stored Procedures. I was thinking maybe something like this to send the EventAccessIds to the Events:

```
WITH first AS
    (
   SELECT EventAccessIds
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserName = @UserName
    ), second AS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM Event
    WHERE EventId = EventAccessIds
    )
```

But how do I break up EventAccessIds = 1+4+8 to EventId= 1, EventId = 4, and EventId = 8?

EDIT
spGetAllEvents

```
USE [Events2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spGetAllEvents]    Script Date: 11/19/2015 9:03:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllEvents]
    @UserName nVarChar(80)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
WITH first 
AS 
( 
    SELECT EventAccessIds 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE UserName = @UserName
), second AS 
(
    SELECT e.* FROM [Event] as e
    WHERE e.EventId in
    (
        SELECT convert(int, s.Data)
        FROM [first] as f
        CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(f.EventAccessIds, '+')) as s
    )
)
END
```

Users (1st image) and Event (2nd image)
[image: Users]

[image: Event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to split `EventAccessIds` with your own function since SQL Server doesn't have `Split` function.


One of the good examples was posted in [Ole Michelsen's blog](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Then, you can use the splited table like an int array:

```
WITH first AS
(
    SELECT EventAccessIds
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserName = @UserName
), second AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Event
    WHERE EventId IN (SELECT CONVERT(int, Data) FROM dbo.Split(EventAccessIds, '+')
)
```

**UPDATED**

Since your [second] query seems to refer `EventAccessIds` selected in [first] query, it should be something like this:

```
WITH first 
AS 
( 
    SELECT EventAccessIds 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE UserName = @UserName
), second AS 
(
    SELECT e.* FROM [Event] as e
    WHERE e.EventId in
    (
        SELECT convert(int, s.Data)
        FROM [first] as f
        CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(f.EventAccessIds, '+')) as s
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is great. Okay I get an error saying "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetAllEvents, Line 31
Invalid column name 'EventAccessIds'." but the column does exist. With the code `WITH first AS
(
    SELECT EventAccessIds
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserName = @UserName
), second AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Event
    WHERE EventId IN (SELECT CONVERT(int, Data) FROM dbo.Split(EventAccessIds, '+')
)
)
SELECT * 
  FROM first f JOIN second s
    ON f.EventAccessIds = s.EventId`

Comment: @RockOn I've updated my answer, try after **UPDATED**. However, `f.EventAccessIds` and `s.EventId` can't be compared because they're string and int. I think you can simply do `select * from [first], [second]`

Comment: Hm okay I tried and now I get: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetAllEvents, Line 39
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Comment: @RockOn Ok, can you post the query of spGetAllEvents and Table structures of Users and Event tables if possible?

Comment: Sure, I just updated my question. By the way, I really appreciate all of your help. :)

Comment: Thanks, I think the error is because `second` is not executed. if you add `SELECT * FROM [second]` in the end, the error will be resolved.

Comment: Yes! That did it. Now it executes and works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand properly what your asking, it's something like this?
[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3892/0)

```
declare @input varchar(max) 
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @result varchar(max) 

set @input = '1+4+8'

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @result = ' + @input

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@result varchar(max)  OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @result=@result OUTPUT
SELECT @result

declare @eventTable table (id int, data varchar(max))
insert into @eventTable select 1, 'Event id 1'
insert into @eventTable select 2, 'Event id 2'
insert into @eventTable select 4, 'Event id 4'
insert into @eventTable select 8, 'Event id 8'

select * 
from @eventTable et
where (id & @result) = id
```